# MS Access Form Filter Date range

Tags: ms-access, vba

I do have an Access form with a dynamic form filter using many controls as criterion. All work just fine excepted for my date range... Here is the piece of code I am using..

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()

Dim strWhere As String
Dim lngLen As Long
Const DMY = "\#dd\/mm\/yyyy\#"

'***********************************************************************

If Not IsNull(Me.PerPNum) Then
    strWhere = "([PNum] = " & Me.PerPNum & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.PerPPro) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([PPro] =  " & Me.PerPPro & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.PerPRev) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([PRev] = " & Me.PerPRev & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.PerDesi) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Uinit] = """ & Me.PerDesi & """) AND "
End If


If Not IsNull(Me.DateStart) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([TaskStart] >= " & Format(Me.DateStart, DMY) & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.DateEnd) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([TaskEnd] < " & Format(Me.DateEnd + 1, DMY) & ") AND "
End If


lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "No criteria", vbInformation, "Nothing to do."
Else

strWhere = Left(strWhere, lngLen)

Me.Debug.Value = strWhere
    Me.Sub_Desi_Schedule.Form.Filter = strWhere
    Me.Sub_Desi_Schedule.Form.FilterOn = True
End If
```

When I look at my "debuger" the WHERE criterion seems just fine.

Howerver I am still getting "Enter Parameter Value" and nothing is displayed even if reenter them.

When not using the date range on my form filters, everything runs smoothly.

Suggestions, ideas is more then welcome.
(please keep in mind that I am not a VB Guru........ So be kind :-) )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you may just be missing date wrappers "#".

Try:

```
"([TaskStart] >= #" & Format(Me.DateStart, DMY) & "#) AND ([TaskEnd] < #" & Format(Me.DateEnd + 1, DMY) & "#)
```

Comment: Nope, I'm wrong. Should have read your code more closely. Your constant has the date wrappers. Sorry. - MrE

Comment: Hi MrE Thats what this part of the code does as a constant
Const DMY = "\#dd\/mm\/yyyy\#"

In my debugger control here is the result:
([TaskStart] >= #01/05/2015#) AND ([TaskEnd] < #01/06/2015#)

I am really scratching my head on this one...

Comment: Did a little more homework this time. It's odd, but i got it to work by removing the WHERE key word: Me.Filter = "[StartDate] >= #05/05/1970" Found it at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-access/mefilter/c07d6930-2ace-46c0-a3e6-e16a2c686500  - Hope that helps, but may cause trouble with your other filters.

Comment: The error you are getting "Enter Parameter Value" usually pops in a query when a field name is misspelled. I would place a break in the code at "Me.Debug.Value = strWhere" then look at "strWhere" in the immediate window (Ctrl+g if you aren't familiar with it, then type "?strWhere <enter>) Copy that and paste it into an empty query in the SQL view. Precede the pasted text with "SELECT * FROM <table or query name that drives your form> Where " and see what it gets you. My best guess is either TaskStart or TaskEnd is misspelled in the source table/query.

Comment: That was it ! Sometimes... The error is too obvious to be seen...
Many thanks MrE !!!